# How to access reference another model in Odoo?

Tags: model, odoo, odoo-12

This is a custom model defined in Odoo 12, it indicates which vehicles are in use on a given day:

```
class DailyVehicleMap(models.Model):
    _name = 'x_vehiclecalendar'
    date = fields.Date("Day", required=True)    
    vehicle = fields.Many2one('fleet.vehicle', 'Vehicle', required=True)
```

Although there are many entries in the `fleet.vehicle` table, they are not accessible to me when I try to add a record to `x_vehiclecalendar`.

[image: screenshot of Odoo view]
When I click the corresponding dropdown field, there is only a "create and edit" option, whereas I was expecting a list of suggestions from the table of vehicles.

If I press "Create and edit" to create a new vehicle entry - it goes to the vehicles table and is visible in the regular vehicle view, but it is *not* visible in the view I made for the `x_vehiclecalendar` model (i.e., the one in the screenshot).

The access rights and record access rules were adjusted such that my current user can do everything:
[image: Access rights]
[image: Record rules]

What is the reason of this behaviour and how can it be corrected?

Comment: how is your xml define? I think you should put some widget like many2one_list or something

Answer (score 0):

I could think of two possibilities XML domain or record access rule,
did you apply any ?

Comment: The record access rules are configured to allow my user all access; I have updated the question with some screenshots. As for the XML domain - how can I check that? I did not perform any XML-related manipulations, perhaps one of them is enabled by default?